# Extending the servlet class to custom class for more customised response

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, inheritance, servlets

In my project, for inserting, updating and deleting the data I am requesting to servlet class and then it process and get back the response.

It all happen via jQuery ajax.

Right now it response only success or failure as follows

```
PrintWriter out =   response.getWriter();
out.println("<custom message>");
```

now i want to make that message more meaningful

By default i will accept 1 parameter called `"format"`, if the format is `null` then by default that particular servlet class will respond in `json` format else only 2 options are going to be there `json` and `xml`.

then i need to set `response.setContentType("application/json");` and etc.

So i will make one servlet class as follows

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class myservlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException,java.io.IOException
    {
        String format   =   req.getParameter("format");

        if(format == null)
        {
            format  =   "json";
        }
        else
        {
            if(format.equals("json"))
            {
                resp.setContentType("application/json");
            }
            else if(format.equals("xml"))
            {
                resp.setContentType("application/rss+xml");
            }
            else
            {
                //error
            }
        }
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException,java.io.IOException
    {
        String format   =   req.getParameter("format");

        if(format == null)
        {
            format  =   "json";
        }
        else
        {
            if(format.equals("json"))
            {
                resp.setContentType("application/json");
            }
            else if(format.equals("xml"))
            {
                resp.setContentType("application/rss+xml");
            }
            else
            {
                //error
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and this above class is extended as follows

import java.io.PrintWriter;

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

public class abc extends myservlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException,java.io.IOException
    {
        PrintWriter out     =   resp.getWriter();
            out.println("{/"id/": /"file/"}");
        //response must be converted to either json or to xml
    }
}
```

will it possible..??

how can i convert response to either `xml` or `json` dynamically...??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this in servlet. This is good occasion to create a filter which will do your converting job.

1. Filter uses [ServletResponseWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponseWrapper.html) and pass it to the servlet
2. Servlet saves a response
3. Filter checks parameter and delegate to appropriate converter (json, xml) - postprocessing.